# Granting dynamodb access to a Glue Crawler?(with terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, terraform, aws-glue

Basically I need to crawl a dynamodb database from one account, with a crawler from another. How do I achieve this?

Following this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/cross-account-access.html
 I get this error:

> Crawler is not authorized to perform:  dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource:  arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:accountA:table/arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:accountB:table/Mytable

As you can see forwhatever reason it is adding the dynamodb's arn over the name. 
So anyone got an idea how to do it properly? Possibly with terraform?